# Generalized eigenspaces of a 4x4 matrix in $Z/2Z$

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, modular-arithmetic

I'm asked to find all the generalized eigenspaces of the following matrix in $Z/2Z$:

\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}

I suppose since it's $Z/2Z$, I can plug in $\lambda = 0$ and $\lambda = 1$. But do I know for sure that both will be generalized eigenvalues?

So I manually calculated the characteristic polynomial (along the first column), and got $t^4 + t^2 = t^2(t^2 + 1) = t^2(t + 1)^2$ confirming both 0 and 1 are eigenvalues.

1. Was that necessary? Was there a better way to get the characteristic polynomial?

Since the algebraic multiplicity of both eigenvalues is 2, I know the highest power of $(T - \lambda I)^n(v)$ is 2. Regardless, by brute force I have to square 2 4x4 matrices and calculate the nullspace of 4 4x4 matrices.

2. Even though it's somewhat simple to do those operations in $Z/2Z$, is there a smarter way to do this? All the manual calculations seem error prone/I'm missing something

Comment: Well, the matrix is singular so $\;0\;$ **must** be an eigenvalue, and since its rank is $\;\ge1\;$ it **must have** an eigenvalue different from zero (in some field extension of $\;\Bbb F_2\;$ , at least) , so $\;1\;$ is the only option here

Comment: What do you mean by the *generalized* eigenspace? Is it the same as the eigenspace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Precisely because it is $\;\Bbb F_2\;$ it seems to be reasonable easy. For example:

$$(T-I)=\begin{pmatrix}
0&1&1&1\\
1&0&1&1\\
0&0&0&1\\
0&1&1&0\end{pmatrix}\;,\;\;(T-I)^2\neq0$$

and thus the geometric multiplicity of $\;\lambda=1\;$ is one, and it is easy to see the same is true for the eigenvalue zero.

For example, it's easy to see that $\;u_0:=(0,0,1,1)^t\;$ is an eigenvector of $\;\lambda=0\;$, and thus $\;V_1=\text{Span}\{u_0\}\;$ , and $\;u_1:=(1,0,0,0)^t\;$ is an engenvector of $\;\lambda=1\;$ ...